# Intellij not picking up maven surefire configuration

Tags: maven, testing, intellij-idea, surefire

In my surefire configuration I have a `classpathDependencyExcludes` entry.

For some reason Intellij does not seem to pick up this configuration (mvn test, does). Is there any way to have Intellij notice my surfire configuration?

Ps.
It seems like something similar has been reported a long long time ago at Intellij ( [IDEA-52286](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-52286) ), but never fixed.

Comment: There seems to be only a workaround to use this feature: manually exclude those dependencies from module settings dependencies. But after a change made to pom.xml it appears again. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206253879-IDEA-not-honoring-maven-surefire-properties<br>I hope jetbrains will fix it soon

Answer (score 1):

Both [IDEA-101185 IntelliJ does not use systemPropertyVariables defined in maven-surefire-plugin configuration](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-101185) and [IDEA-122783 Unit test runner ignores maven surefire classpath configuration](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122783) have been already fixed.

But IDEA still ignores properties from `systemPropertiesFile`.